# Invalid result adding the number of 1s in a binary number

Tags: java, for-loop

I am adding the number of ones in a binary number and have gotten the correct result. However, when I separate the number with spaces it tells me the number's odd.

For example input of: 101 will return even. However, an input of 1 0 1, will return odd.
I would rather return "Not a valid input" if the input contains spaces but I don't know how to do that either.

For some reason when I enter a name with spaces for example "D a n" the program automatically assigns "D" as the binary number and skips the rest.

```
 //Get user input of Name
 System.out.println( "Enter your first name > " );
 String firstName = scan.next( );
 
 System.out.print( "Enter a binary number > " );
 String num = scan.next( );
  
 //Remove special characters/spaces from String firstName
 firstName = firstName.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "");
 firstName = firstName.replaceAll("\\s", "");
 
 //Extract first letter and capitalize
 String firstNameStart = firstName.substring(0, 1);
 firstNameStart = firstNameStart.toUpperCase( );
 
 //Extract remainder of name
 String firstNameRemainder = firstName.substring( 1 );
 firstNameRemainder = firstNameRemainder.toLowerCase( );     
 
 //Concatenate name
 firstName = firstNameStart + firstNameRemainder;

 //Print name properly
 System.out.println("\n" + firstName);

 //Analyze binary number 
 if (String.valueOf(num).matches("[0-1]+")){
   
 // Sum of 1's in the binary number
      int res = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < num.length(); i++)
      {
        if(num.charAt(i) == '1')
          res = ++res;
      }     
         {
         if (res % 2 == 0)
             System.out.println("Even.");
           else 
             System.out.println("Odd.");
           }
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with binary numbers. You're analyzing strings with ones and zeros.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Scanner#nextLine`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine--) to read the entire line.

```
String firstName = scan.nextLine( );
System.out.print( "Enter a binary number > " );
String num = scan.nextLine( ).replaceAll("[^01]", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

If not specifically set, [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)*'s* `next()` method will stop when it reaches the default delimiter, which is a **blank space**.

- When you insert `1 0 1` it stops at the first blank space, and gives you the result (`1` is odd).
- When you insert the name with blank spaces, the first part will be assigned to the name, and the second `next()` will just continue reading the first input string until the next blank space is found (*assigning it to the binary number in your code*).

If you want the delimiter to be `\n`, *that is, when you push `Enter` on your keyboard*, you could call `nextLine()`, which will instead read the line until `\n` is found.

---

In order to get the number correctly, and check wether it's even/odd, if there are blank spaces in the input, you should:

```
String line = scanner.nextLine().trim(); //removes whitespaces
int number = Integer.parseInt(line);     //converts it to a number

//check if the integer is even/odd
if ((number & 1) == 0) 
{ 
   //it's even!
   ...
} 
else 
{ 
  //it's odd!
  ....
}
```

Comment: So I fixed the next. to nextLine(), however when I enter a number now with spaces such as: 1 0 1 1 , instead of printing Odd, the output resorts to Error the number contains numbers and letters which is part of my if else statement.  Is there a reason the code:
if Sting.valueOf(num).matches("[0-1+") is somehow messing up because of the spaces?

Comment: You could first trim() the String and then convert it into an Integer, updating the answer